# How can I find the formula for a cycloid with a given speed?

Tags: geometry, circles, curves, cycloid

I know that for a cycloid with radius $R$ and time $t$, it can be defined as $x = R(t - \sin t)$ and
$y = R(1 - \cos t)$. However what if it's not at unit speed and we have a speed $z$/sec such that after $t$ seconds the centre is at $(tz, R)$.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem

Comment: @Arch S, it is valid for all speeds.

Comment: The exact problem is that if I have a point on the rim of a circle of radius R that is at point (0,0) at t = 0. The circle rolls at speed z on the x axis such that after t seconds the centre is at point (zt, R). What is an equation for the point that was at (0,0)?

Comment: @SarGe I assume the formula is for unit speed, that is when z = 1. How would I alter it for any given z?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following parametrisation of the cycloid:
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x(\varphi) &= R ( \varphi - \sin\varphi ) \\
y(\varphi) &= R ( 1 - \cos \varphi ) \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
What happens if you now choose $\varphi = z t$?